MudMenuItems of MudMenu always appear in the upper left corner
I use MudBlazor in my Blazor website.
The MudMenuItems of MudMenu always appear in the upper left corner not on the MudMenu element itself. No matter what I do the menu always opens in the top left corner.
Also only the example menu from the MudBlazor page itself has this problem.
All other MudBlazor items work normally!
What could be the reason?
<MudAppBar Class="custom-appbar" Fixed="true" >
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h2" Class="custom-appbar-text" >Name</MudText>
    <MudSpacer />
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Class="custom-appbar-text-user">@userName</MudText>
    <MudMenu Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.MoreVert" Class="custon-menu" AriaLabel="Open user menu">
        <MudMenuItem>Profile</MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenuItem>My account</MudMenuItem>
        <MudMenuItem>Logout</MudMenuItem>
    </MudMenu>
    <div class="logo-container">
        <MudImage Src="images/logo_1.png" Alt="logo1" Class="appbar-logo" Elevation="5"/>
        <MudImage Src="images/logo_2.png" Alt="logo2" Class="appbar-logo"  Elevation="8"/>
    </div>
</MudAppBar>

.custon-menu {
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-top: 450px;
  z-index: 2; 
}

The error also occurs outside the MudAppBar, all CSS and JavaScript files are loaded correctly.
I also cannot find a CSS entry that triggers this error.

Since you provided no css code of other elements, please check if custom-appbar or other parent elements contain conflicting styles. Also this should not be the issue but in case, modify your custon-menu to custom-menu.

You can control the behaviour of the MudMenuItem with AnchorOrigin and TransformOrigin on the MudMenu
The default value for both is Origin.TopLeft
See the documentation MudMenu Placement and its snippet
So for your case I would suggest AnchorOrigin="Origin.TopCenter" aswell TransformOrigin="Origin.TopCenter"
<MudMenu ... AnchorOrigin="Origin.TopCenter" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopCenter">
    <MudMenuItem>Profile</MudMenuItem>
    <MudMenuItem>My account</MudMenuItem>
    <MudMenuItem>Logout</MudMenuItem>
</MudMenu>

Snippet

Thank you for your reply, yes I am aware of this, unfortunately it is completely ignored.
The MudMenuItems always open left at the top although my MudMenu item itself is at the bottom right of the web page.

I start a sample with default blazor project template with your code. https://i.sstatic.net/51Rj8NIH.png I t behaves differently from your description, so you could provide a minimal reproducible example. This is usually a css-conflicting issue and have you followed the installation of MudBlazor ? https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#ready-for-more?

@RaffaelMüller what version of MudBlazor are you using? Does it happen on every screen size?

I use MudBlazor 7.8.0, the funny thing is when I move the MudMenu element with margin-top it works.
Only when I move it with margin-left does this error occur.
